# How to redirect stdin to a FIFO with bash

Tags: bash, fifo, mkfifo

I'm trying to redirect stdin to a FIFO with bash. This way, I will be able to use this stdin on an other part of the script.

However, it doesn't seem to work as I want

### script.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/in -f
mkfifo /tmp/in
cat >/tmp/in &

# I want to be able to reuse /tmp/in from an other process, for example : 
xfce4-terminal --hide-menubar --title myotherterm --fullscreen -x bash -i -c "less /tmp/in"
```

Here I would expect , when I run `ls | ./script.bash`, to see the output of ls, but it doesn't work (eg the script exits, without outputing anything)

What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: Why do you need a FIFO, instead of just reading from standard input when necessary?

Comment: Because the thing that needs standard input runs in a different process (see updated question)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.  When `cat` is passed `/dev/stdin` as an argument, it refers to the stdin of `cat`, not that of your shell (seems that way on my Linux system, at least).  `cat` without arguments copies its stdin to its stdout, and with `/dev/stdin` as its only argument it does the same thing.  I suspect this is not what you want.

Comment: No, that is exactly What i want, i want to redirect stdin to a fifo. I will remove the /dev/stdin since it is already implicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that less need additional -f flag when reading from pipe.

```
test_pipe is not a regular file (use -f to see it)
```

If that does not help I would also recommend to change order between last two lines of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/in -f
mkfifo /tmp/in

xfce4-terminal --hide-menubar --title myotherterm --fullscreen -x bash -i -c "less -f /tmp/in" &

cat /dev/stdin >/tmp/in
```

Comment: What is the difference between using `cat /dev/stdin > /tmp/in` and reading from standard input directly with `less -f /dev/stdin`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I avoid the use of /dev/stdin, because I get a lot of surprises from what is exactly /dev/stdin, especially when using redirects.

However, what I think that you're seeing is that `less` finishes before your terminal is completely started. When the `less` ends, so will the terminal and you won't get any output.

As an example:

```
xterm -e ls
```

will also not really display a terminal.

A solution might be `tail -f`, as in, for example,

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /tmp/in
mkfifo /tmp/in
xterm -e "tail -f /tmp/in" &

while :; do
    date > /tmp/in
    sleep 1
done
```

because the `tail -f` remains alive.